# Facebook timeline - none of my comments or likes on friends posts show on my timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

None of my comments or likes on friends posts show on my Timeline. They are all in my Activity Log and are all marked as 'allowed on Timeline'.  The only things visible on my Timeline are my own direct posts or shares, nothing else. This has been the case ever since the change for me from Wall to Timeline - ie a few months now.  Can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Posts that you liked or commented won't appear in your `Timeline` unless you shared them. The liked post will appear to your friends on their `news feed` according to their `news feed settings`. This is not a glitch, it's an intended behavior.
`Allowed in Timeline` means, if your friends can see this activity on their news feed or not