# Why aren't friends posts I like showing in my timeline?

Tags: facebook-timeline, facebook-like

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook timeline - none of my comments or likes on friends posts show on my timeline](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/29497/facebook-timeline-none-of-my-comments-or-likes-on-friends-posts-show-on-my-tim)

When I check 'like' on friend's Facebook timelines of photos or comments, they do not show up in my timeline even though many are open to the public or other friends.

I had a look in the privacy settings, but there is nothing on changing the 'like' settings, and I have set everything to allow friends to see.

On the activity log page my likes are listed, so here I tried to change the setting for each one individually.  When I scrolled over circles on the right of each individual post it says that it is 'allowed in timeline' but when I click on the circle I only get the option to 'unlike'.  I looked at 'Hidden' under the 'All' tab (on the upper right of screen) but I have nothing there.
Still on the same page, I went to the 'activity log' tab (on the upper left of screen) and scrolled down to 'LIKES', but it only lists music, movies & books, etc and these show up fine in my timeline.

I would appreciate if anybody can help me resolve the issue, or is this a glitch in FB?

Answer (score 0):

Posts that you liked or commented won't appear in your `Timeline` unless you shared them. The liked post will appear to your friends on their `news feed` according to their `news feed settings`. This is not a glitch, it's an intended behavior.
`Allowed in Timeline` means, if your friends can see this activity on their news feed or not